# How to Copy database files to Documents directory using visual studio installer project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a project in Asp.Net windows forms application, I have make an Exe of this project, but I want to copy Database files in documents directory during installation. How can I do this using visual studio installer project.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps like below:

1. Create a folder named "database" in your Visual Studio project.
2. Copy the database file *.mdf to the "database" folder.
3. Modify your connection string for the .mdf file like below (this is a sample)

   connectionStrings

   ```
       <add name="WindowsFormApp.Properties.Settings.TestConnectionString"
                   connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\data.mdf;Initial Catalog=MainDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```

   /connectionStrings

The database file will autoattach when you execute the application. Database name is MainDatabase.